# android gridview subitems start activity onclick

Tags: java, android

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,second.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this,second.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I know this method but lets say for example i have 20 subitems so i need 20 activities !! how do i make it so only one activity is passed in but the data inside it changes depending on the subitem clicked ( by the data inside it i mean simple Textviews ) sorry my english is very bad

Comment: Does the text differ, or the layout of the activity differs as well for each element?

Comment: no !! the same layout !! just different text inside the textviews

Comment: Then look at the answer below That should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a extra to the activity intent to indentify where you came from:

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, second.class);
    i.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then in your activity you can get the intent that like this:

```
int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity); //if your activities have different layouts depending the given position, you can move this line inside the switch function
    ...
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position", 0);
    }
    switch(position){
        case 1:
            //do something
            break;
        case 2:
            //do another thing
            break;
        default:
            //default behaviour
            break;
    }
}
```